# Regex logical OR

Tags: c#, regex

This is a purely academic exercise relating to regex and my understanding of grouping multiple patterns. I have the following example string

```
<xContext id="ABC">
<xData id="DEF">
<xData id="GHI">
<ID>JKL</ID>
<str>MNO</str>
<str>PQR</str>
<str>
<order id="STU">
<str>VWX</str>
</order>
<order id="YZA">
<str>BCD</str>
</order>
</str>
</xContext>
```

Using C# Regex I'm attempting to extract the groups of 3 capital letters.

At the moment if I use pattern `>.+?</` I get

```
Found 5 matches:
>JKL</
>MNO</
>PQR</
>VWX</
>BCD</
```

If I then use `id=".+?">` I get

```
Found 5 matches:
id="ABC">
id="DEF">
id="GHI">
id="STU">
id="YZA">
```

Now I'm trying to combine them by using logic OR `|` for each term on both sides `id="|>.+?">|</`

However, this isn't giving me the combined results of both patterns

My questions are:

1. Can someone explain why this isn't working as expected?
2. How can I correct the pattern to get both results shown combined in correct order listed
3. How can I further enhance the combined pattern to just give letters only? I'm hoping it's still `?<=` and `?=<` but just want to check.

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want, but if you just want groups of three capital letters `\b([A-Z]{3})\b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex doesn't know where to start or stop the alternativ options separated by `|`. So you need to put them in subpatterns:

```
(id="|>).+?(">|</)
```

However, [regex is not the right tool to parse XML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1633117)

Those round brackets also add capturing subpatterns. This can be returned by themselves. So this:

```
(id="|>)(.+?)(">|</)
```

will return the whole match at index 0, the front-delimiter at index 1, the actual match you want at index 2, and the last delimiter at index 3. In most regex engines you can do this:

```
(?:id="|>)(.+?)(?:">|</)
```

to avoid capturing the delimiters. Now index 0 will have the whole match, and index 1 only the 3 letters. Unfortunately, I can't tell you how to retrieve them in C#.

Comment: Thanks - this also gives the correct answer! I usually test the c# ones here http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 2):

You need to group the alternatives together

```
(?:id="|>).+?(?:">|</)
```

And to get the letters only use [positve lookbehind and lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=id="|>).+?(?=">|</)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32b5t)

The groups starting with `?<=` and `?=` are zero width assertions, that means, they don't match (what they match is not part of the result), they just "look" behind or ahead.

Comment: Are you sure variable length lookbehind is allowed in c# regex?

Comment: Also a lookbehind is less efficient I think, because the string has to be traversed twice. So I think it's a bit overkill in this situation. Of course, it's a more general and thus rather elegant solution ;).

Comment: @m.buettner - It may be okay about performance, as it saves some ticks on not creating backreference (as your code does).

Comment: Haha, fair enough. Someone should probably profile it before making such claims ^^. I just wanted to bring it to mind that lookbehinds can generally incur some overhead.

Comment: @Ωmega, yes c# is the only language I know without restrictions on the lookbehinds.

Comment: @stema - Thanks for that information. I was not sure, as I code regex in Perl. Should I switch to C#..? :)) I wish Perl makes this possible as well...

Answer (score 1):

I would **suggest** you to use regex pattern `(?:(?<=id=")|(?<=>)).+?(?=">|</)`

Test it [here](http://regexr.com?32b63) on RegExr.

Answer (score 1):

Capturing groups FTW!

```
@">(?<content>.+?)<|id=""(?<content>.+?)"""
```

Specifically, *named* capturing groups, because the .NET regex flavor lets you use the same group name as many times as you want in the same regex.  Calling `Groups["content"]` on the Match object will return the content without regard to its location (i.e., between two tags or in an `id` attribute).